# angularjs2: setting fields to "dirty", especially datepicker

Tags: forms, typescript, angular

I am new to Angular2/Typescript, since I come from the Java world, I decided to learn Typescript and Angular2 directly.

I want to leave most of the logic on the server, thus I don't need complex validation management on the client. So all I want is the user to fill out forms, and post/put all the fields to the REST Service.The goal is to leave the client side as light as possible.

I have a form:

```
<form role="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #ArbeitstagForm="ngForm">
```

and a field in it, some datepickers too: similar like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="datepicker" [(ngModel)]="model.datum">
```

When I submit the form, I call this function:

```
model = new Arbeitstag();

onSubmit(form:any) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(this.model));return false;
}
```

So that alerts me the the entered data as JSON, which I will after send to a REST Service. It works actually great, BUT only when I actually type something into the field, when I have a default value, or I set the field with a datepicker, the model object values will remain empty.

I've found out about the dirty setting of the fields, which are false by default and are getting true when I type something in and that's also what I see when I check firebug, but that's definitely not what I want to achieve.

Is there a way to set all the fields dirty in a form in Angular2? I've found many examples for Angular.js 1, but not for Angular2/Typescript.

Comment: Why do you want that? `dirty` is to indicate that a user modified the field.

Comment: Yes, but only if the user TYPES into the field (click into the field, type some chars with the keyboard), but when the user is clicking a button, and that button/javascript function behind is setting the value (-> datepicker), the field is not becoming dirty, thus is not updated in my model object..

Answer (score 2):

`Control` has a `markAsDirty()` (and `markAsTouched()`) method

```
<input #datePicker="ngForm" type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="datepicker" [(ngModel)]="model.datum">

<button (click)="datePicker.control.markAsDirty()">update dirty status</button>
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/LFC9rL2xUkThrM2PaKJz?p=preview)

Comment: I was missing a `.control`. Updated my answer and added Plunker.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is get a reference to the form in my component, using `ViewChild`. With that reference I can mark to form dirty or touched when I need to. Like so:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('form') form: NgForm;
  ...

  public methodWithFormChange(): void {
    this.form.control.markAsDirty();
  }
}
```

;-)